# рандомное целое число в select option

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="periodicity">
<option value="3">1-20
</option><option value="25">20-40
</option><option value="50">40-60
</option></select>
```

Можно ли сделать так чтоб при выборе например 1-20 задавалась рандомное значение из этого же промежутка и аналогично 20-40, 40-60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
//
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------

var sel = document.querySelector('select');

sel.addEventListener('change', function () { 
  // Get min and max from text
  var val = sel.selectedOptions[0].text.split('-')
  // Set value to selected option
  sel.selectedOptions[0].value = getRandomIntInclusive(+val[0],+val[1])
  console.log(sel.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="periodicity">
  <option value="3">1-20
  </option>
  <option value="25">20-40
  </option>
  <option value="50">40-60
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте `addEventListener` "change" на селект и отслеживайте `value`. А далее

```
// Возвращает случайное число между min (включительно) и max (не включая max)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random